# How do I find the mean of summed values across multiple Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Edit: I've realized that I did not ask my question in the right way. I'm not going to accept one answer over another, but am going to leave all content here for anyone's future use.

I have a value that I'm looking to compute across on-going DataFrames.

I have df1:

```
Name    |   Col1   | Col2  
----------------------------
'Silvers'|    7    |   1       
'Jones'  |    7    |   2       
'Jackson'|    4    |  NaN      
'Merole' |   NaN   |   2       
'Kanoff' |   NaN   |   5       
'Walker' |   NaN   |   8        
'Smith'  |    8    |   0
```

I'd like to sum the `Col1` and `Col2` columns that results in a new column, `Col3`. I already have a solution that sums correctly if there is a value present in both columns, returns the non-null value if there is a NaN value present, and returns NaN if both values are NaN. So that resulting DataFrame, `df2` would look like this:

```
Name    |   Col1  |  Col2  |  Col_Sum 
-------------------------------------
'Silvers'|    7    |   1   |     8   
'Jones'  |    7    |   2   |     9   
'Jackson'|    4    |  NaN  |     4  
'Merole' |   NaN   |   2   |     2   
'Kanoff' |   NaN   |   NaN |    NaN  
'Walker' |   NaN   |   8   |     8   
'Smith'  |   NaN   |  NaN  |    NaN
```

For `df3`, when I have new data, I'd like to perform the same sum operations as I did above, but then find the average of *only* the non-null values that were included in the summation in prior DataFrames.

I want this for `df3`:

```
Name    |   Col1   |  Col2 |  Col_Sum |    Cols_Avg 
-------------------------------------------------------
'Silvers'|    3    |   3   |     6    |      3.5
'Jones'  |    1    |   6   |     7    |       4
'Jackson'|   NaN   |   9   |     9    |      6.5
'Merole' |   NaN   |  NaN  |    NaN   |       2
'Kanoff' |   NaN   |   7   |     7    |       7
'Walker' |    4    |   8   |     12   |      6.67       
'Smith'  |   NaN   |  NaN  |    NaN   |      NaN
```

I'd then like to continue that trend with each new DataFrame of data that I get, summing the values and computing their averages based on how many values there are for the same row across all the Dataframes. I'm not sure how to accomplish this or if I'm even using the correct tools to do so. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How have You calculated average = 3.5 at the first row?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to `pd.merge` df2 and df3 based on name, and you simply compute the Cols_Avg over the four original columns, Col1 and Col2?

Comment: Is it just me, or have all numeric values completely changed in the third example DataFrame compared to the first two? The `Cols_Avg` logic is unclear to me.

Comment: @ipj I got 3.5 by summing the df2 values 7 + 1 = 8. Then I summed the df3 values 3 + 3 = 6. Then I summed both of those sums 8 + 6 = 14 and divided by the total number of non-null values in row 1 of both dataframes.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler the values are different because it's a different set of data, but with the same Name values.

Comment: @Will Wild: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @RuthgerRighart I've realized that I did not ask my question in the right way. I'm not going to accept one answer over another, but am going to leave all content here for anyone's future use.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use `pd.merge`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Silvers', 'Jones', 'Jackson', 'Merole'], 'Col1':[7,7,4,np.nan], 'Col2':[1,2,np.nan,2]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Silvers', 'Jones', 'Jackson', 'Merole'], 'Col1':[3,1,np.nan,np.nan], 'Col2':[3,6,9,np.nan]})

dfn = pd.merge(df2, df3, on='Name')
dfn['ColsAvg'] = dfn.mean(axis=1)
```

For ease I put everything in a new DataFrame `dfn`. If you want to put `ColsAvg` in df3 as you write, sure this is possible.